# How to get seconds into human readable dates

Tags: c++, time

I'm trying to turn arbitrary integer values representing the seconds since Jan 1, 1970 into human readable dates.

This is as close as I've gotten, but I keep getting the current date. How can I get a `struct tm` of a date that is not the current date?

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <string>
#include <time.h>

using namespace std;

int main() {
  struct tm * timeStruct;
  time_t myTime = 946684800; //s from 1970 to 2000
  int timeStamp = time(&myTime); //I thought this would set the date to the values of myTime, it just sets it to now
  timeStruct = localtime(&myTime);
  cout << timeStamp;
  cout << "\n";
  cout << asctime(timeStruct); //This should read Jan 1, 2000, instead it keeps giving me the current time
  cout << "\n";
  system("pause");
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Well that's because `time` returns the current time. Your way of trying to use it is not supported.

Comment: `gmtime` and `mktime` might help you?

Comment: @Sneftel I've edited my title to more accurately reflect the question. I was concerned that I'd get answers that would misinterpret my intent.

Answer (score 0):

`time(&myTime)` was setting the value of myTime to the current time (this is *apparently* to be expected).

Solution:

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <string>
#include <time.h>

using namespace std;

int main() {
  struct tm * timeStruct;
  time_t myTime = 946684800; //s from 1970 to 2000

  int timeStamp = myTime;
  timeStruct = localtime(&myTime);

  cout << timeStamp;

  cout << "\n";

  cout << asctime(timeStruct);

  cout << "\n";

  system("pause");

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Also time_t is in seconds, not milliseconds. You did it correctly, but the comment says `ms` which is a bit confusing.

Comment: C++ does not guarantee that a `time_t` value represents then number of seconds since 1970. Your code is not portable.

Comment: "Apparently"? https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/c/time - *`time` - Returns the current calendar time encoded as a std::time_t object, and also stores it in the object pointed to by arg*"

Comment: @john this is for one of my own internal tools, so that doesn't matter too much to me... yet. Is there a good solution that would be portable?

Comment: @GlenPierce Not that I'm aware of. You could try [Boost.Date_Time](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_68_0/doc/html/date_time.html)